# About the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I know maybe it is so simple, but I stuck at it. Suppose that the matrix $A$ satisfies $A^2=Identity$. How can we derive something about the eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Let $ \lambda $ be an eigenvalue.

this means there exists a vector $ X\ne 0 $ such that

$$A.X=\lambda.X$$
thus

$$A.A.X=A^2.X=\lambda.A.X=(\lambda)^2.X$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ (prove this!)  If $A^2$ is the identity, the only eigenvalue of $A^2$ is $1$.  What does that tell you about the eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Try to think about what it means for a matrix to be its own inverse. ANswer :

Let $Ax=\lambda x$. Then we have $A^2x=\lambda Ax \implies x=\lambda A x \implies x= \lambda^2x \implies \lambda = \pm 1.$